# Fragments for GridView item?

Tags: android

Is it possible to use Fragments inside a GridView?

I have tried to do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        Rune rune = (Rune) getItem(position);
        RuneFragment runeFragment = new RuneFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(parent.getId(), runeFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        runeFragment.renderRune(rune);

        convertView = parent.findViewById(R.id.rune_grid_fragment);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "" + convertView); //====> null
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

but turns out convertView is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        // edited ，add your layout here
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        Rune rune = (Rune) getItem(position);
        RuneFragment runeFragment = new RuneFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(parent.getId(), runeFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        runeFragment.renderRune(rune);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "" + convertView); //====> null
    }
    return convertView;
}
```